# Signal Level at the Input of Antenna

Tags: networking, signals, wireless

I am taking a Wireless Networks course and I have a midterm next week. While I am studying to this lesson I got stuck in one question which I dont have any clue for.

The question is the following ;

> A transmitter generates a 15 dBm signal and is connected to an antenna
>   using a cable that induces a 3dB loss.The cable has two connectors
>   that induce a loss of 2 dB each. What is the signal level at the input
>   of the antenna?

In my notes, I don't have any formulas or clue about how I'm gonna solve this one.

Could anyone help me about it please?

Thanks by advance.

Comment: I'm not exactly a signal processing expert, but wouldn't your "formula" basically be "original signal - losses = final signal"?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about computer networking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm taking the same course, below you can see the answer

1. Signal loss for 2 connectors = 2 * 2dBm = +4dBm
2. Signal loss for the cable = +3dBm
3. Total Loss = 4dBm + 3dBm = +7dBm 
   Therefore, signal level at the input of the antenna = +15dBm - 7dBm = +8dBm